# htaccess change url to one more friendly

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, user-experience

I could recently make some of my urls more user friendly.

But now I have some problems to could change other ones.

for example this one:
https://ugocd.com/ilustracion-filtro?id=Retrato%20Digital&rubro=ilustracion

I would like to be more easy to read like:

https://ugocd.com/ilustracion/Retrato-Digital

Can anyone have some idea how to do this please using htaccess?

Thank you,

I tried this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$

RewriteRule ^ilustracion/(.*)? ilustracion-filtro?id=$1&rubro=$2 [L]
```

But it does not work, I also wan to replace spaces like this "%20" with this "-"

I'm not a developer I'm just a designer and I dont understand why this does not work I've tried many things but nothing works :( I even see tutorials in youtube.

And even worst I'like to make it work for other pages like this:
https://ugocd.com/diseno-web-filtro?id=UI,%20SEO%20y%20Maquetaci%C3%B3n%20HTML%20CSS3&rubro=diseno_web

https://ugocd.com/animacion-filtro?id=After%20Effects%20y%20Premier%20Pro&rubro=animacion

etc

Comment: You will find literally _thousands_ of existing answers here on SO that explain exactly what you ask. Just take a look around, read through a few existing answers, that way you will find a solution and learn how to handle the tools you want to use. You need the `AllowOverride` directive and a combination of a `RewriteCond` and a `RewriteRule`. It is straight forward.

Comment: If you fail to implement a solution yourself, then claiming "it doesn't work" does not help. What should we do with that? All we could do is repeat the existing answers. Because things _do_ work. If they don't work for you then you need to find out _why_ . We can help with that, help find the issue you ran into, but for that you need to give us much more details: you attempt of an implementation, where you made that implementation, how you tested and what actually happened _exactly_ .

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found something that works for me and may be helpful for others:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^diseno-web/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)$ diseno-web-filtro?id=$1&rubro=$2
```